# Retrieve record based on LastModifiedDate with JsonArray Iteration in java

Tags: java, json

I have this input data. I need to retrieve the record's `Id` based on `LastModifiedDate` by performing iteration over `jsonArray` (here `records` is our jsonArray).

Can anyone please help me to achieve this?

Input data:

```
{
   "totalSize":2,
   "done":true,
   "records":[
      {
         "attributes":{
            "type":"Lead",
            "url":"/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000BHayREAT"
         },
         "Id":"00Q5500000BHayREAT",
         "LastModifiedDate":"2020-07-17T08:06:16.000+0000"
      },
      {
         "attributes":{
            "type":"Lead",
            "url":"/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000BHayHEAT"
         },
         "Id":"00Q5500000BHayHEAT",
         "LastModifiedDate":"2020-07-17T08:07:16.000+0000"
      }
   ]
}
```

What I tried:

**Step1**: adding each record date to list

```
String recordsList="InputData";
            List<Date> lastDate = new ArrayList<Date>();
            String LeadID=null;
            try {
                JSONArray recs = new JSONArray(recordsList);
                
                for (int i = 0; i < recs.length(); ++i) {
                    JSONObject rec = recs.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(rec.has("LastModifiedDate"))
                    {
                        String LastModifiedDate = rec.getString("LastModifiedDate");
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
                        Date date = null;
                        try {
                            date = formatter.parse(LastModifiedDate);
                            System.out.println("date::::::::::" + date);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid in LastModified Date Format");
                        }
                        lastDate.add(date);
                    }
                }
                lastDate.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
                Object highestLastModifyDate = Collections.max(lastDate);
                System.out.println("highestLastModifyDate:::::" + highestLastModifyDate);
```

**Step2**: matching each record date with highestLastModifyDate and retrieve Id

```
for (int i = 0; i < recs.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject rec = recs.getJSONObject(i);

    if(rec.has("LastModifiedDate"))
    {
        String LastModifiedDate = rec.getString("LastModifiedDate");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date date2 = null;

        try {
            date2 = formatter.parse(LastModifiedDate);
            //System.out.println("date2::::::::::" + date2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid in LastModified Date Format");
        }

        if (date2 != null && highestLastModifyDate.equals(date2)) {
            System.out.println("date2::::::::::" + date2);
            LeadID = rec.getString("Id");
        }
      }
  }

  System.out.println("LeadID::::::::::" + LeadID);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note:** the code shown here will work, but is there any efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: which version of java do you use?

Comment: Hi @ Iurii Drozdov,

I am using jdk1.8.0_65 and let me know further steps if any